# Is it possible to disable logging entirely in Python Twisted?

Tags: python, logging, twisted

I notice that the generally accepted solution is to send it to /dev/null. However, by design, the log file gets rotated whenever a SIGUSR1 gets sent to twisted. This will then rotate /dev/null, which is undesired. In fact, I have half a mind to think that this is a bug.

Anyway, does anyone know how to circumvent this?

Comment: In what context?  Are you writing your own main?  Some library code?  Are you running twist?  twistd?  Some other Twisted-provided CLI?  Some third-party CLI?

Comment: I am running twistd with a python file as an argument (-y).

Comment: I see that the twisted man page says, for --logfile, that "-" is for stdout. Would I just specify "--logfile=-" and then pipe that the /dev/null? Or am I misreading the usage?

Comment: You can't use `--logfile=-` if you want to let it daemonize.  If you don't need it to daemonize, `twist ... > /dev/null` should work.... except `twist` doesn't support `-y` so you'll have to port to a plugin.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need it to daemonize...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom logger that doesn't actually log anything:

```
# yourlogger.py
from zope.interface import implementer
from twisted.logger import ILogObserver

@implementer(ILogObserver)
class NullObserver(object):
    def __call__(self, event):
        pass
```

Make sure it is importable and then ask for it from the command line:

```
$ twistd --logger yourlogger.NullObserver -y ...
```